Assign unique user identifiers for Jupyter-based web application
I am developing an web application using Jupyter notebook which is being rendered with voila. I have deployed the app on my private server (nginx). Now I want to create individual files for each user accessing my application. I want to assign a unique session ID or some identifier to each user and create file with that unique identifier so that while accessing the files (need to perform read/write operations) it doesn't get mixed up.
I was hoping to assign users their unique files based on their IP addresses, but I can't figure out how to do this. Any kind of help is much appreciated!
